# taking div full screen on ios (similar to video audio element full screen)

Tags: ios, fullscreen

Is it possible to open a div (without video or audio element in full screen using .webkitRequestFullScreen() using safari Element class on iPad?
(similar to how you can open video element in full screen mode covering the toolbars).

Or is this only possible if you call objective-c function using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's docs, it is only possible on Windows & Mac.

"n Safari 5.1 and later for Mac OS X and Windows, you can not only take your video into full-screen mode, you can take any HTML element into full-screen mode."

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html